# speed of mysql query with interval

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
$sql="delete from table where date_add(created_at, INTERVAL 2 DAY) < now()"
```

The query executes in more than 10 seconds. Why is the  query so slow? How to improve speed of executing? Thanks!

Comment: Have you got on index on your created_at field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query won't be using the index on `created_at` as you are altering the value. This also means that MySQL has to add 2 days to `created_at` for every row. You can alter the date you are querying with to ensure the index is used and the date modification only happens once.

```
delete from table where created_at < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an index on your `created_at` field, you you haven't already done.

I also suggest you to read current date with a separated SQL, and then compare directly the returned date:

```
$sql = "SELECT date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) ";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$now_minus2days = $row[0];
```

So your new SQL to delete become:

```
$sql = "delete from table where created_at < '$now_minus2days'";
```

This should make sure that MySQL uses index to delete.